# Trouble reproducing SubtleCrypto in Crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, node-crypto, subtlecrypto

I have some code utilizing SubtleCrypto that encrypts a key and stores it in a database.

For another functionality i have to be able to encrypt it in Node 12. Without SubtleCrypto i have to recreate the functionality in Crypto.

I get output of the same size, but it dosen't seem to be decryptable by SubtleCrypto and i'm trying to figure out where i'm going wrong.

This is the code running with SubtleCrypto on browsers:

```
key = getKeyMaterial(password)];
salt = base64ToArraybuffer(optionalSalt)
aesKey = crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
{
    name: constants.algorithms.pbkdf2,
    salt: salt,
    iterations: pbkdf2Iterations,
    hash: { name: constants.hash.sha256 },
},
key,
{
    name: constants.algorithms.aesGcm,
    length: aesWrapKeyBitsLength,
},
true,
['wrapKey', 'unwrapKey']
),
return {
  salt: arraybufferTobase64(salt),
  aesKey: aesKey,
}


function getKeyMaterial(password) {
var enc = new TextEncoder();
crypto.subtle.importKey(
  constants.format.raw,
  enc.encode(password),
  {
    name: constants.algorithms.pbkdf2,
  },
  false,
  ['deriveKey']
)
```

Without SubtleCrypto, in Node 12, I'm forced to work with the Crypto library..
This is my, current iteration of the, code.

```
const ivByteLength = 12;

function wrapKey(privateKey, aesKey) {
  const IV = crypto.randomBytes(ivByteLength);
  const ALGORITHM = 'aes-256-gcm';

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, aesKey, IV);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(privateKey, undefined, 'binary');
  encrypted += cipher.final('binary');

  const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag();

  encrypted += authTag;
  const output = {
    wrappedKey: arraybufferTobase64(Buffer.from(encrypted, 'ascii')),
    iv: arraybufferTobase64(IV),
  };
  return output;
}

async function deriveAesGcmKey(password, salt) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 100000, 32, 'sha256', (err, derivedKey) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(derivedKey);
    });
  });
}

function arraybufferTobase64(buffer) {
  let binary = '';
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return btoa(binary);
}

function base64ToArraybuffer(base64) {
  const binary = atob(base64);
  const len = binary.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    bytes[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

The wrapped key have the same size in both implementations, but the one generated by Node cannot be unwrapped in the browser.

Am i assuming some defaults wrong or something?

Comment: What should the WebCrypto code actually do? `getKeyMaterial()` only imports the password as `CryptoKey`. `deriveKey()` generates an AES key using PBKDF2, which may be used for key wrapping/unwrapping. Nowhere is a key encrypted. You should post the full WebCrypto code and also define the constants. Also, sample data would be nice. Currently the NodeJS code does significantly more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NodeJS has something called `webcrypto` Class inside `crypto` package, that has subtle crypto implementation.

Example from the [Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#webcrypto_crypto_subtle):

```
const { subtle } = require('crypto').webcrypto;

async function digest(data, algorithm = 'SHA-512') {
  const ec = new TextEncoder();
  const digest = await subtle.digest(algorithm, ec.encode(data));
  return digest;
}
```

Also check out: https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#webcrypto_class_subtlecrypto

**Edit:**

As said in the comments for lower version of Node you can use a polyfill like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@peculiar/webcrypto its a webcrypto implementation for Nodejs version higher than Node10

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunately only available in Node 15 and Node 16, which are not yet available on Aws Lambda. So i'm stuck without it. :/

Comment: @berinder edited the answer you can take a look at the polyfill package.